# How to get local file system path in azure websites

Tags: azure

I have a file hosted on the disk along with my website that I want to read .Not sure how do I access the file when I use System.Environment.CurrentDirectory it point to a D drive location .Can someone please tell me how can I get to my file stored at the root of where my site is hosted.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an environment variable called HOME in your website's environment that will get you part way there.

You can access it using razor syntax or in code (C#).  For example, suppose you have a file called data.txt that is at the root of your site with the default document and the rest of your files.  You could get it's full path like this.

```
@{ var dataFileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME").ToString() + "\\site\\wwwroot\\data.txt"; }
```

You can find this out on your own using the Site Control Management/"Kudu".  For example, if your website is contoso.azurewebsites.net, then simply navigate to contoso.**scm**.azurewebsites.net.  In here you can learn all about the file system and environment variables available to your website.

Comment: I'm doing the same on Azure and I got "D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\NewFolder\FileName.json", but I still cannot access... WHY!!?!?!? I know the file is there as I can see it on Kudu... What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

For testability, I use below code.

```
string path = "";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")))
    path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + "\\site\\wwwroot\\bin";
else
    path = ".";
path += "\\Resources\\myfile.json";
```

In above example, I added `myfile.json` file to `Resources` folder in a project with `Content` and `Copy if newer` property setting.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in both localhost and azure:

```
Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "file_at_root.txt");
```

`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` is the full local path to your site's root.

Comment: FYI: Running this in Azure gave me : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory='D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11090\'     Which was not close to "D:\home\site\wwwroot\"

Comment: @granadaCoder Thanks, It has worked for me, but I updated it with HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, which should give you "D:\home\site\wwwroot\" in Azure.

Comment: It seems that HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath will give the path granadaCoder mentioned when running in Azure Functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` (.NET Core project). It returns "D:\home\site\wwwroot\" in Azure and the application root in local so the only difference is adding "bin\\" when it is Azure. I am searching the entire directory tree, just in case, but it can be trimmed.

It's something like:

```
private static string GetDriverPath(ILogger logger, string fileName)
{
    var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, fileName)))
    {
        return path;
    }

    string[] paths= Directory.GetFiles(path, fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    if (paths.Any())
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(paths.First());
    }

    throw new FileNotFoundException($"{fileName} was not found in {path}.", fileName);
}
```

I'm new answering questions and this is an old one but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the below code.

```
string fullFilePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") != null
    ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot\test.txt" //It will give the file directory path post azure deployment
    : Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + @"\test.txt";//It will give the file directory path in dev environment.
```