# File Based Artifacts for App Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm new to app-functions.  But I have successfully created a custom app function that will accept some JSON.

When my JSON is uploaded, my app-function will want to validate it against a schema.  The JSON will be in the body of the POST request to more accurately describe what is going on.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm

Here is basic code for validation:

```
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties':
  {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type':'string'}
    }
  }
}";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
}");


IList<string> messages;
bool valid = person.IsValid(schema, out messages);
```

Where the above code has

```
string schemaJson
```

I would like to have a local file saved that I load and verify.

In actuality, I will have several files, and one of the parameters in the http-request will trigger which file I use to json-schema-validate.

Let's image that "mycustomerid" is passed in the header of the http-request (or a query-string or whatever), and the value for mycustomerid will drive which schema I want to validate the input json.

So I would have several files.

```
customer_1.jsonschema 
customer_2.jsonschema 
customer_3.jsonschema
```

**What is the best-practice to store these files are necessary for my fairly simple app-function?**

```
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
```

APPEND:

This was my final answer using the accepted answer here AND what I found here: [How to get local file system path in azure websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333545/how-to-get-local-file-system-path-in-azure-websites/37589466#37589466)

```
            string rootDirectory = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")))
            {
                /* running in azure */
                rootDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + "\\site\\wwwroot";
            }
            else
            {
                /* in visual studio, local debugging */
                rootDirectory = ".";
            }
        string path = rootDirectory + "\\MySubFolder\\MyFile.jsonschema";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1. Create a file 'schema.json' in 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerCSharp1' using Kudu Console
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console

Step 2. Code for your HttpTrigger to read file content as string:

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME").ToString() + "\\site\\wwwroot\\HttpTriggerCSharp1\\schema.json";

    string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);

    log.Info(readText);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello ");
}
```

Comment: Alexey, see my append for something I learned about "local" vs "in azure"